# How to decrease CPU Usage in Spark App (python)

Tags: python, tcp, spark-structured-streaming

I've built spark app in python3 with this architecture:

### 1.ws_server --> json_data
2.json_data--> spark app(socket streaming)
3.spark app(socket streaming) --> POST & PUT requests to get some data using API on the side and load it back to service system

Although everything works fine, and spark is listening in live and sending right data, I'm getting 100% CPU usage and don't know how to solve it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDh4W.png)

> My ideas: it's about setting up a good config file, maybe it's about saving memory in the process of aggregation of dat frame in every batch, at least UDF requests.

I don't see any large cpu usage at every step, guess it has some default settings I haven't known

I was running scripts in terminal like this at the beginning:(ofc separately)

```
python3 ws_server.py
python3 spark_app.py
```

Then I studied spark-submit using config file:

```
spark-submit spark_app.py --conf "spark_defaults.conf"
```

Attention: there is no problem in spark reading this configs(I checked it by picking random parameters at first)

Here how my scripts look like:

### ws_server.py

```
import socket
import sys
import time
import json
import argparse
import datetime


def get_message():
    with open('path_to_json/data.json',
              'r') as file:
        json_str = file.read()
    dict_data = json.loads(json_str)
    data_list = list(dict_data.values())
    return " ".join(data_list) + "\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Streaming generation socket server")
    parser.add_argument("port", type=int, help="port")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    port = args.port

    print(port)

    HOST = "127.0.0.1"
    PORT = port

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print('Socket created')

    try:
        sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print('Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg))
        sys.exit()

    print('Socket bind complete')

    sock.listen(1)
    print('Listening on {}'.format(PORT))

    while True:
        try:
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            print('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("bye")
            sock.close()
            sys.exit()
        except:
            print("Error when accept connection")
            sock.close()
            sys.exit()

        while True:
            try:
                conn.send(get_message().encode())
                time.sleep(30)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("bye")
                sock.close()
                sys.exit()
            except:
                print("Client disconnect")
                break
    sock.close()
print("Done")
```

### data.json

```
{"value": "xxx_data,yyy_data"}
```

### spark-defaults.conf

```
spark.driver.memory              449m
spark.driver.cores               1
spark.executor.cores             1
spark.executor.memory            1g
spark.executor.instances         1
spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout      true
spark.storage.safetyFraction 0.9
spark.storage.memoryFraction 0.6
```

### spark_app.py

> ```
> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
> from pyspark import StorageLevel
> from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, split, udf, col, to_timestamp
> import requests, json
> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>
>
>
> def add_data_to_service(#it's working, private info):
>     url = '200 response all good.com/api/v2/get_needed_data'
>     headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
>     params = {
>         'its also': 'good'
>     }
>     res = requests.patch(url, json.dumps(params), headers=headers)
>     print('status code', res.status_code) #always 200 and putting data successfully
>
>
> def split_data(df):
>     # Split column into two columns
>     split_cols = split(df['data_together with , separator'], ',')
>     new_df = df.withColumn('some data1', split_cols.getItem(0)) \
>         .withColumn('some data2', split_cols.getItem(1)) \
>         .withColumn('timestamp', split_cols.getItem(2))
>     return new_df
>
>
> def execute_Request(number: str):
>     url = 'it's also working fine'
>     r = requests.get(url,
>                      params={
>                          'needed params': 'needed params',
>                          'api_key': 'its private'
>                      },
>                      headers={
>                          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
>                      })
>     response = r.json()
>     print(response)
>     if r != None and r.status_code == 200:
>         return response['what i need']
>     else:
>         return None
>
>
> def split_response(df):
>     split_cols = split(df['response'], ',')
>     new_df = df.withColumn('data1', split_cols.getItem(0)) \
>         .withColumn('data2', split_cols.getItem(1)) \
>         .withColumn('data3', split_cols.getItem(2)) \
>         .withColumn('data4', split_cols.getItem(3))
>     return new_df
>
>
> def transform(lines):
>     df_streamed = lines.select(
>         explode(
>             split(lines.value, " ")
>         ).alias("data_together with , separator")
>     )
>     # times data is streamed
>     wordCounts = df_streamed.groupBy("data_together with , separator").count()
>     # splitting data from socket
>     splitted_data = split_data(wordCounts)
>     no_duplicates_df = splitted_data.select("*").where("count < 2")
>     # prepare execution
>     executeRestApiUDF = udf(execute_Request)
>     # collecting response data
>     df_with_request_data = no_duplicates_df.withColumn("response", executeRestApiUDF(col("contact")))
>     final_df = split_response(df_with_request_data)
>     return final_df
>
>
> def load_data(df, epoch_id):
>     df_pandas = df.toPandas()
>     if (df_pandas.empty):
>         pass
>     else:
>         lead = str(df_pandas['data1'].iloc[-1])
>         city = str(df_pandas['data2'].iloc[-1])
>         country = str(df_pandas['data3'].iloc[-1])
>         region = str(df_pandas['data4'].iloc[-1])
>         timezone = int(df_pandas['data5'].iloc[-1])
>         add_data_to_service(data1, data2, data3, data4, data5)
>         # df_dropped = df.drop(columns=['B', 'C'])
>
>
> def main(spark: SparkSession):
>     spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
>
>     print('we start\n')
>     lines = spark \
>         .readStream \
>         .format("socket") \
>         .option("host", "127.0.0.1") \
>         .option("port", 8069) \
>         .load()
>
>     transformed_df = transform(lines)
>     query = transformed_df.writeStream.outputMode("update").foreachBatch(load_data).trigger(
>         processingTime='10 seconds').start()
>     query.awaitTermination()
>
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     main(SparkSession
>          .builder
>          .config("spark.driver.memory", "449m")
>          .config("spark.driver.cores", "1")
>          .master("local[1]")
>          .appName("test")
>          .getOrCreate())
> ```

Comment: As an aside, use `conn.sendall(get_message().encode())`. `send` isn't guaranteed to send all of the data. It returns the number of bytes sent with the expectation of another send with the rest of the data.

Comment: Do a preliminary debugging and post a [mre] with debugging details. Are you sure it persistently uses 100% CPU while the input is idle? If it's reproducible, why not post [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SPARK/issues)?